# How to install Restkit via CocoaPods?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.3, restkit, cocoapods

After adding `Restkit` to the `Podfile`:

```
 platform :ios

 dependency 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '1.2'
 dependency 'RestKit', '0.10.1'
```

and run:

```
 $ pod install
 Updating spec repo `master'
 Using Facebook-iOS-SDK (1.2)
 Using SBJson (2.2.3)
 Generating support files
```

RestKit is not installed. How can I install `RestKit` by `CocoaPods`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on information of this [pull request](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/253), updated the `Podfile` to:

```
platform :ios

dependency 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '1.2'
dependency 'RestKit', '0.10.1'
dependency 'RestKit/Network', '0.10.1'
dependency 'RestKit/ObjectMapping', '0.10.1'
dependency 'RestKit/ObjectMapping/CoreData', '0.10.1'
dependency 'RestKit/ObjectMapping/JSON', '0.10.1'
dependency 'RestKit/ObjectMapping/XML', '0.10.1'
dependency 'RestKit/UI', '0.10.1'
```

or update to the latest (0.6.2.rc2) `cocoapods` by:

```
gem install cocoapods --pre
```